# How to interweave divs in display: flex?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, frontend

This is a little hard to explain in just text so I'm including an image:
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecBVv.png)

Right now I have 2 divs in `display: flex` and want to create something which works for mobile view as well ... however I need to 'interweave them'

what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: use the concept of `order` in flex box.. and media queries to handle the `order`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't really do what the image describes using two parent `div`s, short of messing about with absolute positioning which you almost certainly don't want to be doing. Without the provision of a minimum reproducible example of your actual html and css it's tricky to say that for sure.

As you are making a two dimensional layout, you would likely be better served having a single parent `<div>` with `display: grid` set. Something like this (this [code is also available on codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/VwGpoKX))

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child--1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="child child--2">Div 2.1</div>
    <div class="child child--3">Div 2.2</div>
</div>


.parent {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
}

.child {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.child--1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.child--2 {
    grid-row: 1;
}

.child--2,
.child--3 {
    min-height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 64rem) {
    .parent {
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    .child--1 {
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    }

    .child--2 {
        grid-row: 1;
        grid-column: 2;
    }

    .child--3 {
        grid-row: 2;
        grid-column: 2;
    }
}
```